# RPM installation Trino throws python dependency

Tags: python, linux, presto, rpm, trino

I'm trying to install Trino using RPM on Red Hat Enterprise Linux distribution. I install the Trino dependencies using the following commands:

```sh
$ sudo yum update -y
$ sudo yum install -y java-11-openjdk.x86_64 python3
$ sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3
```

Then I try to install Trino from archive in single-node mode. This however gives a dependency error:

```sh
$ sudo rpm -i trino-server-rpm-368.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    python >= 2.4 is needed by trino-server-rpm-0:368-1.noarch
```

This error doesn't make sense to me given that this dependency is actually satisfied when checking my python version:

```sh
$ python -V
Python 3.6.8
```

Comment: Looks like its flagged as an issue on Trino Github: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/10743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answers has been provided by @hashhar on this Github Issue if you actually have the correct dependencies installed:

```sh
$ sudo rpm -i --nodeps trino-server-rpm-368.rpm
```